# Saving an OptionMenu selection to a variable in Tkinter for python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, openpyxl, optionmenu

I am making a GUI in Tkinter that has the user input information and writes it to an excel via openpyxl. I have a few OptionMenu widgets in there and I want to be able to save whatever the user selects from the dropdown menu to a variable that I can then write to a file. 
Here is what I have so far:

```
    self.equipment = StringVar(top)
    self.equipment.set("10077")
    self.e18 = OptionMenu(top, self.equipment,'10077','G2143','G2145','17727')
    self.e18.grid(row=13, column=1, sticky=E+W)
```

Later, in another function I assign it to a variable:

```
    equipment = self.equipment
```

I then write it to a file:

```
    ws1['D18'] = str(equipment)
```

When I open the file, instead of the user selected string showing up in the cell, this does: PY_VAR16

All the other information entered in Entryboxes write to excel perfectly. Anybody know how to save the OptionMenu selection to a string so that it will write to excel? Is there an equivalent of a .get() command for this widget? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an equivalent of a .get() command for this widget?

According to [this page](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm), StringVars do indeed have a `get` method. I suggest replacing

```
ws1['D18'] = str(equipment)
```

With

```
ws1['D18'] = equipment.get()
```

Comment: I was working for hours on this and I swear i tried that, but I guess not. Thank you!